Who is Hanako's first 2D crush?
In the last segment of the last episode of the anime, Narumi asks the group who their first love in 2D is, and Hanako's reply is "Yuki Amami", which upon a quick Google search seems to point to a Japanese actress known for being an otokoyaku, or an actress designated to play the male roles.
However, being a real person, she is by definition not 2D, and neither does the trivia section on Fandom link to her, nor anyone else, so I am utterly confused: Hanako's not totally clueless like Naoya regarding anime and video games, so it couldn't have been her misunderstanding what is asked.
So who is this Yuki Amami?
Is he/she some lesser-known anime or video game character, or the Yuki Amami referenced in that Wikipedia article?
If the latter, what kind of reactions is the (non-)reply supposed to invoked in us viewers?
I thought Hanako's sexual orientation is straight, though she often indulges in some wild yaoi fantasies, so would her first and current 2D crush being a Bifauxnen make her bisexual?

The reactions of Japanese viewers seemed to refer to the same actress (e.g. "she is not 2D lol"), but there's not much commentary about it.

@AkiTanaka I think in the manga, the name is annotated with a "2.5D" below the speech bubble, but she's not even a prolific VA for anime or video games, so it still comes out as random to me.

OK, according to https://artsandculture.google.com/story/what-is-2-5-dimensional-2-5d-culture-ministry-of-economy-trade-and-industry-meti/YgUBMKSPP6O3LQ, stage productions and cosplays are 2.5D, so it kind of is a valid answer (for 2.5D anyway), though not something the average anime and manga fans are overly familiar with.
